# Parted: Partition 1 (/dev/sdb1) not accessible after partition resize using parted

Tags: linux, partition, parted

I used `parted` tool to shrink the main volume so that I can create a new partition on the HDD (capacity 2TB). I read articles and tried multiple options, like, `GParted`. But that didn't help.

I was a little comfortable with parted, which I used earlier. So, I gave it a shot. Created a 200GB (`label: msdos, fs: fat32, type: primary`) partition with the existing partition shrinking to 1.7TB.

Now the second partition(/dev/sdb2) can be mounted and used. But, I am not able to use the first partition (/dev/sdb1). I have 500GB of data stored in it, which I would not like to lose.

I googled about how possibly I can check/fix the problem and found `fsck` tool. Checked the first partition using `fsck /dev/sdb1`, returned back to the prompt with `fsck from util-linux 2.31.1` printed as an output to the console.

Similarly, checked for the partition 2 and got following output:

```
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt. 1) Remove dirty bit 2) No action ?  `
```

I didn't took any action though, as I was fearful of damaging the disk. Looking for help on getting the partition 1 back, even if I have to compromise for the second partition.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Did you shrink the filesystem first?

Comment: What filesystem was on the partition you resized?

Comment: Post this: `sudo fdisk -lu`. And FAT32 not recommended for larger partitions. It has no journal so dosfsck may not work or may take forever. You also cannot store any file over 4GB on FAT32.